# If the circle $x^2+y^2+4x+22y+c=0$ bisects the circmuference of the circle $x^2+y^2-2x+8y-d=0$ the...

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems

Problem : 
If the circle $x^2+y^2+4x+22y+c=0$ bisects the circmuference of the circle $x^2+y^2-2x+8y-d=0$ then c +d equals

(a) 60

(b) 50

(c)  40

(d) 30

Solution : 
Equation of common chord of the circles is given by $S-S'=0$ where $S = x^2+y^2+4x+22y+c=0 ; S' = x^2+y^2-2x+8y-d=0$

$\Rightarrow  4x+22y+c-(2x+8y-d)=0$

$\Rightarrow 4x+22y+c-2x-8y+d =0$ 
$\Rightarrow c+d = -(2x+14y)$

Now how to get the value of c +d , please suggest thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Common chord has equation $6x+14y+c+d=0$ and it must pass through the center $(1,-4)$ of $S'$. Thus $c+d=50$.

Answer (score 2):

you had an error:
$$S-S'=4x+22y+c-(-2x+8y-d)\\=6x+14y+c+d=0$$
so
$$c+d=-6x-14y$$

because $S$ besects $S'$, so the center of $S'$ is on the line $S-S'$. The center is $(1,-4)$, so
$$c+d=-6*1-14*(-4)=50$$